# ARM deployment of API Managment creates echo service

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I get that having the `Echo service` and various predefined products creates a better out-of-the-box experience, but for DevOps purposes, I'd hoped that when using the Azure ARM templates these default artifacts weren't created.

Is there a backdoor way to NOT create them - nothing stood out in the [schema](https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2016-07-07/Microsoft.ApiManagement.json), but I was hoping there was a "createDemoExperience" property or something we could set to false.

I know I can delete these resources after the fact via the REST API, but there really shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: Hey Jim, you are not the first person to ask for this.  I'll bring it up with the team.

Comment: I suggest you to go here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/31826548-do-not-deploy-echo-api-when-deploying-via-the-sdk to vote for this feature